# Swift Keypath: How do I join them together and reference Arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, append, keypaths

I want to understand SWIFT Keypaths better and in particular:

1. Create keypaths including multiple levels
2. Create keypaths which subscript into arrays
3. Join keypaths together
4. Understand the types of keypaths

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, are those 4 different questions?

Comment: Maybe my format is not right for this. It took me a couple of hours to get clear on keypaths in swift. It was a significant amount of searching to get clear on keypaths - especially question 2 wasn't easy to find anything on. I wanted to share this with others on Stack Overflow so I asked and answered at the same time - a miniguide to Keypaths if you like. My motivation is to save time fro others when they are trying to understand keypaths. Perhaps there's a better way to do this on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with these structs:

```
struct Pet {
  var name: String
}

struct Address {
  var postcode: String
}

struct Person {
  var name: String
  var age: Int
  var address: Address
  var possessions: [String]
  var pets: [Pet]
}
```

and these variables:

```
let john = Person(
  name: "John",
  age: 50,
  address: Address(postcode: "BS1 9ZZ"),
  possessions: [ "Book",
                 "Laptop" ],
  pets: [ Pet(name: "Linga"),
          Pet(name: "Pharaoh") ]
)

let addresses: [Address] = [ Address(postcode: "ABC"),
                             Address(postcode: "DEF") ]
```

**1) Create keypaths including multiple levels**

```
print("Field")
print(john[keyPath: \Person.name])         // John
print(john[keyPath: \Person.possessions])  // ["Book", "Laptop"]

print("Nested fields")
print(john[keyPath: \Person.address.postcode])  // BS1 9ZZ
```

**2) Create keypaths which subscript into arrays**

```
print("Array lookup")
print(addresses[keyPath: \[Address][1] ])   // Address(postcode: "DEF")

print("Multilevel with array")
print(john[keyPath: \Person.possessions[1]])   // Laptop
print(john[keyPath: \Person.pets[0].name])     // Linga

print("Multilevel using normal indexing")
print(john[keyPath: \Person.possessions][1])               // Laptop
print(john[keyPath: \Person.pets][0][keyPath: \Pet.name])  // Linga
```

**3) Join keypaths together**

```
print("Join keypaths")
let kp1: KeyPath<Person, Address> = \Person.address
let kp2: KeyPath<Address, String> = \Address.postcode
let kpboth = kp1.appending(path: kp2)
print(john[keyPath: kpboth])

print("Join keypaths including array")
let kpa = \Person.pets
let kpb = \[Pet][0]
let kpc = \Pet.name
let kpall = kpa.appending(path: kpb).appending(path: kpc)
print(john[keyPath: kpall])  // Linga

print("Join keypaths inline")
print(john[keyPath: (\Person.pets).appending(path: (\[Pet][0])).appending(path: (\Pet.name))])  // Linga
```

**4) Understand the types of keypaths**

The Type of a keypath is:

```
KeyPath<FromType, ToType>
```

where FromType is the input type and ToType is the output type.

So the type of the keypath: \Person.pets is

```
KeyPath<Person, [Pet]>
```

because this starts with a Person and finds an array of Pets.

Similarly the type of the KeyPath: [Pet][0] is:

```
KeyPath<[Pet],Pet>
```

because this starts with an array of Pets and finds a Pet.

When joining Keypaths the type of the output of the keypath on the left must match the type of the input of the KeyPath on the right.
We can see this clearly if we repeat the earlier example but showing explicit types:

```
print("Join keypaths including array with Explicit Types")
let kpA: KeyPath<Person, [Pet] > = \Person.pets
let kpB: KeyPath<[Pet],  Pet   > = \[Pet][0]
let kpC: KeyPath<Pet,    String> = \Pet.name
let kpALL = kpA.appending(path: kpB).appending(path: kpC)
print(john[keyPath: kpALL])    // Linga
```